# $Z$ transform with $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation

I was trying to solve this $z$ transform $(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{4})\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4})$ giving values to $\sin$ and $\text{cosine}$, I have understand that every $8$ the sequence will be equal : 
$(-1)^{(n/2)}$* this values for those 7 values..

$n=0$:  $0$

$n=1$:  ${1}/{\sqrt(2)}$

$n=2:  0$

$n=3 :   {1}/{\sqrt(2)}$

$n=4:    0$

$n=5: -{1}/{\sqrt(2)}$

$n=6: 0$

$n=7: -{1}/{\sqrt(2)}$

So, I can divide for each case $8k , 8k+1 , 8k+2,8k+3,\cdots ,8k+7$ but it will be pretty slow. So i have two questions:

This is a valid way? and

is there some fastest way ?

Comment: If you know that the coefficients are $k$-periodic, then the $z$ transform is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ times $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{nk}=\frac{1}{1-z^k}$.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't there be some $i$'s around for the $(-1)^{n/2}$?

Comment: But before that i have (-1)^(n/2)  so i think that i have to divide in 8 cases.. ?

Comment: I can leave it there and than apply the definition of z transform where the n goes to make the sum of a geometric serie

Comment: There's no need for that. If the whole thing is $8$-periodic, write down $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_7$, then the generating function will be $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^7 a_k z^k}{1-z^8}$.

Comment: But (-1)-^(n/2) isnt 8 periodic... @ian

Comment: Only the second part is 8 periodic so how i can get the z transform ?

Comment: The entire thing put together is $8$-periodic, since the first part is $4$-periodic, the second part is $8$-periodic, and the last part is $4$-periodic again, and $8$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Why (-1)^(n/2) is 4 periodic? I can't get that

Comment: Write $n=4k+j$ for integers $k,j$, then $n/2=2k+j/2$ so $(-1)^{n/2}=(-1)^{2k} (-1)^{j/2}=(-1)^{j/2}$ since $(-1)^{2k}=1$.

Comment: but this way is a bit slow... if i have to divade by 8 cases....

Comment: Given that all 8 cases are easy to evaluate it doesn't seem like that big of a deal. Alternatively though, you could write $\cos((n+4)\pi/4)=-\cos(n\pi/4)$, which would allow you to write the whole thing in terms of a polynomial of degree $3$ times $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{4n}=\frac{1}{1+z^4}$ instead.

Comment: sorry i haven't understand ... i have to divide that in 8 cases like :  (-1)^((8n+1)/2) *1/sqrt(2) , (-1)^((8n+5)/2) *-1/sqrt(2)  and all the others case ?

Comment: Approach 1: the $z$ transform is $\left ( \sum_{k=0}^7 a_k z^k \right ) \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{8n}$. The idea of this approach is that a shift by $8$ changes nothing. Approach 2: the $z$ transform is $\left ( \sum_{k=0}^3 a_k z^k \right ) \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{4n}$. The idea of this approach is that a shift by $4$ achieves multiplication by $-1$. Either way you need to compute the first few $a_k$ to put into the polynomial part.